# Incorrect Sharepoint Picture path

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I am not able to find the correct image path. Sharpoint is somehow adding incorrect image in profile page.

the only occurs when I go to friends wall.
my profile picture's is correct.

in below path `9090/sites/mysite` is incorrect this should be `6060`

```
http://*******:9090/sites/mysite/User%20Photos/Profile%20Pictures
```

I tried to search for `9090`but it is no where in the solution.

I also changed path in Manage User Profiles.

but still it contains incorrect path

Comment: Have you extended the mysite web application or done any other changes?

Comment: yes before that my URL contain 9090 port number but now I have created a new web application with 6060 port number

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem after extending my web application to a new adress, and had to update the user profile pictures url to get the pictures to show normally again.

Use the cmdlt **Update-SPProfilePhotoStore** in PowerShell.

```
Update-SPProfilePhotoStore -MySiteHostLocation "http://MySiteNewLocation" -OldBaseUri "http://MySiteOldLocation/User Photos/Profile Pictures/" -NewBaseUri "http://MySiteNewLocation/User Photos/Profile Pictures/"
```

[Update-SPProfilePhotoStore](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607547.aspx)

**Update**

The first parameter "**MySiteHostLocation**" should be the full url to the mysite webapplication with the protocol - "http://ghokmapd02:6060" and

"**OldBaseUri**" should be "http://ghokmapd02:9090/User Photos/Profile Pictures/" - **If this were your old URL**

"**NewBaseUri**" should be "http://ghokmapd02:6060/User Photos/Profile Pictures/".

```
Update-SPProfilePhotoStore -MySiteHostLocation "http://ghokmapd02:6060" -OldBaseUri "http://ghokmapd02:9090/User Photos/Profile Pictures/" -NewBaseUri "http://ghokmapd02:6060/User Photos/Profile Pictures/"
```

Comment: running above command gives me below error. why it is adding "Profile Pictures" twice in path

Update-SPProfilePhotoStore : Error processing the photo URL
http://ghokmapd02:6060/User Photos/Profile Pictures/Profile
Pictures/_7701180_MThumb.jpg for user \7701180: The file
http://ghokmapd02:6060/User Photos/Profile Pictures/Profile
Pictures/_7701180_MThumb.jpg does not exist.
At line:1 char:1
+ Update-SPProfilePhotoStore -MySiteHostLocation "http://ghokmapd02:6060"
-OldBase ...

Comment: See me updated answer. And see if you can add the whole error message that you received.

Comment: -OldBaseUri "http://ghokmapd02:9090/sites/mysite/User Photos/"
My old photoes are in this place

Comment: Update-SPProfilePhotoStore : Error processing the photo URL
http://ghokmapd02:6060/User Photos/Profile Pictures/Profile
Pictures/_7701180_MThumb.jpg for user \7701180: The file
http://ghokmapd02:6060/User Photos/Profile Pictures/Profile
Pictures/_7701180_MThumb.jpg does not exist.
At line:1 char:1
+ Update-SPProfilePhotoStore -MySiteHostLocation "http://ghokmapd02:6060"
-OldBase ...
+     + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (:) [Update-SPProfilePhotoStore], Fi   leNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.PowerShell.
   SPCmdletUserProfilePhotoStore

Comment: This is the command
C:\Users\spadmin> Update-SPProfilePhotoStore -MySiteHostLocation "http://ghokmapd02:6060" -OldBaseUri "http://ghokmapd02:9090/User Photos/Profile Pictures/"
-NewBaseUri "http://ghokmapd02:6060/User Photos/Profile Pictures/"

Comment: You need to specify the full path using protocols, have you tried this?

Comment: I am adding http with paths. I think stackExchange removed them from my comment